# Deploy Nuxt sitemap with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I have a sitemap created with nuxt and firebase but when I deploy the site to firebase the sitemap throws and error since I am referencing my fireInit file but my nuxt.config.file has been moved to my firebase functions folder so I can deploy it. When I try to add the fireInit file in my firebase functions folder I then get an error because I am importing outside a module. Also when I take out my dynamic routes by commenting out my async routes function the site map doesn't show my custom domain url. It shows the https://us-central1-PROJECT_NAME.cloudfunctions.net.

**File Structure**

```
functions/
- nuxt.config (prod)
- index.js

 public/
- _nuxt/ (client)

 src/
 - nuxt.config (dev)

 firebase.json
```

**Nuxt Config**

```
module.exports = {

     modules: ['@nuxtjs/sitemap'],

    sitemap: {
        hostname: process.env.BASE_URL,
        exclude: ['/listings/create', '/listings/edit', '/profile/**'],
        async routes() {
            const { db } = require('./plugins/fireInit');
            const snapshots = await db.collection('listings').get();
            return snapshots.docs.map((doc) => `/listings/${doc.id}`);
        },
    },
}
```

**./plugins/fireInit**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'KEY',
    authDomain: 'KEY',
    projectId: 'KEY',
    appId: 'KEY',
    measurementId: 'KEY',
};

// init firebase
!firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : '';

// init services
export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Comment: About the `hostname`, it seems your `process.env.BASE_URL` is empty. Can you try to force the value if null ? eg.  `hostname: process.env.BASE_URL || 'https://example.com/'`

Comment: Thanks so much! I fixed my static links. Do you know how to fix the dynamic links? Also do you know process.env.BASE_URL would be null in production but not development?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the firebase web in functions and import it outside a module.
You have to read Firestore via firebase-admin on your index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
```

And in your sitemap config:

```
sitemap: {
    hostname: 'YOUR HOST',
    exclude: ['/listings/create', '/listings/edit', '/profile/**'],
    async routes() {
      const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('listings').get()
        return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => `/listings/${doc.id}`);
    },
},
```